# PHPMailer File Attachment

Tags: php, html, web, phpmailer, contact-form

I've been working on a website with a contact form. Everything is working fine except that the attachment isn't mailed. Here are the HTML and PHP files:

(And this is the first time I ask question in this website, I apologise for this terrible formatting, thanks in advance)

```js
<? php
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $email_address = $_POST['email'];
}
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
}
if (isset($_POST['comment'])) {
  $message = $_POST['comment'];
}

$body_message = '<p>You have a new message from your website contact form.</p> </br> </br> <p> Here are the deatils:</p> </br> </br> <p>Name: </p>'.$name.
'<p>Email: </p>'.$email_address.
'<p>Phone: </p> '.$phone.
'</br> <p>Message: </p> </br>'.$message;


$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail - > IsSMTP();
$mail - > Host = 'mail.ronaldtest.com';
$mail - > Username = 'Ronald@ronaldtest.com';
$mail - > Password = '151588';
$mail - > Port = 587;
$mail - > addAddress('ronaldng1588@gmail.com');

$mail - > setFrom('ronald@ronaldtest.com', 'Brighten Management Auto Mailer');

$mail - > Subject = 'Website Contact Form: $name';
$mail - > Body = $body_message;

if (isset($_FILES['attachmentFile']) && $_FILES['attachmentFile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  $mail - > AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']['tmp_name'],
    $_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']);
}


$mail - > IsHTML(true);


if ($_POST["submit"]) {
  if (!$_POST['name']) {
    $error = "<br />Please enter your name";
  }
  if (!$_POST['email']) {
    $error. = "<br />Please enter your email address";
  }
  if (!$_POST['phone']) {
    $error. = "<br />Please enter your phone number";
  }
  if (!$_POST['comment']) {
    $error. = "<br />Please enter a comment";
  }
  if ($error) {
    $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger" There were error(s)
            in your form: '.$error.
    '</div>';
  } else {
    if (!$mail - > Send()) {
      $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, there was
                    an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
    } else {
      $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank you, <strong>'.$_POST['name'].
      '</strong>!   I will be in touch!</div';;
    }
  }
}


?>
```

```html
<section id="contact">

  <? php include ( 'email.php'); ?>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="feature_header text-center">
          <h3 class="feature_title">Keep In <b>touch</b></h3>
          <h4 class="feature_sub">Contact us for future improvements</h4>
          <div class="divider"></div>
          <?php if (isset($result)){ echo $result; } ?>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="contact_full">

          <form method="post">
            <div class="col-md-6 left">
              <div class="left_contact">
                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="form-level controls">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="input-block" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?php 
                                            if (isset($_POST[" name "])){
                                                echo $_POST['name']; }?>"/>
                    <span class="form-icon fa fa-user"></span>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="form-level controls">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="input-block" placeholder="Your Email" value="<?php 
                                            if (isset($_POST[" email "])){
                                                echo $_POST['email']; }?>" />
                    <span class="form-icon fa fa-envelope-o"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="form-level controls">
                    <input type="phone" name="phone" class="input-block" placeholder="Your Phone Number" value="<?php 
                                            if (isset($_POST[" phone "])){
                                                echo $_POST['phone']; }?>" />
                    <span class="form-icon fa fa-phone"></span>
                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 right">
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-level controls">
                  <input type="file" name="attachmentFile" id="attachmentFile" value="<?php echo $_FILES['attachmentFile']['tmp_name'] ?>" />
                  <span class="fa fa-file"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-level controls">
                  <textarea class="textarea-block" name="comment" rows="4" value="<?php 
                                            if (isset($_POST[" comment "])){
                                                echo $_POST['comment']; }?>"></textarea>
                  <span class="form-icon fa fa-pencil"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-main featured" value="Submit Now" />
            </div>

          </form>

        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What do you see, what happens? Any errors? Messages? Any other clues?

Comment: Next time, look at the examples provided with PHPMailer. While the chosen answer fixes your immediate problem, you are not handling uploads safely, so go read the examples anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a form to upload a file it has to have  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag. so in your case:

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```